# How do I import files into GarageBand on iPod touch?

Tags: garageband

I'm trying to import the m4a files that iTunes synchronized from the Voice Memo app, but the files are not showing up in the GarageBand app in iOS when I open it.

Any idea how to import these sound files?

Comment: change the tempo before adding the track, you'll get a lot more time per track.. so you won't have to split as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To import audio files into Garageband for iOS, connect your iOS device to your computer. Then do the following:

#### On your computer:

1. Open iTunes
2. Click your device in the left-hand column
3. Click "Apps" in the bar at the top of the right-hand pane
4. Under "File Sharing" select "Garageband" in the "Apps" column
5. Click "Add..." in the bottom-right of the "GarageBand Documents" area
6. In the dialog that opens up, select the file(s) you want to transfer over
7. Once you've selected the file(s), it transfers over to your iOS device.

   [image]

#### On your iOS device:

1. Open GarageBand
2. If you're not already, switch to the multi-track view by tapping the [image] button
3. In the upper right-hand area, you should see a loop icon with the number of newly transferred files on top of it, like this:

   [image]
4. Tap this icon. It brings up a screen like this:

   [image]
5. Just like the screen says, you can tap and hold and drag the desired audio files into your track listings. They each appear as Audio Recorder tracks:

   [image]

That's it!

There is one caveat: GarageBand for iOS is limited to a maximum of 320 "bars" for the length of a project, and it does not appear that it's possible to bypass this. If you need to edit audio that's longer than that, you will need to use another app.

Comment: Great! I wasn't finding it on the app itself, thanks!

Comment: @Tom Glad I could help!

Comment: Sad it will import only till the 24th second.. :/ I have an 1 hour recording I would like to edit on it.

Comment: @TomBrito Make sure your Garageband song section length is set to "automatic" - tap that small "+" under the gear to change it. Once it's set to automatic, your entire file should be editable, assuming you have enough space on your device.

Comment: I got more space now, but looks like the maximum of what they call "bars" is 320, and it fits just a few minutes (about 5). Maybe the only solution is to split the audio before importing... :/

Comment: @TomBrito Hm, you're right. Sorry, I didn't realize this limitation.